# Android gridview and paging

Tags: android

I want to make paging with android `GridView`, but first I want to know if anyone has an idea of how to do that.

Answer (score 5):

One way is to put your grid views in a [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) and then flip with an animation.

Use setInAnimation() and setOutAnimation() to set the animations and flip the pages with showNext() and showPrevious()